# multipartFile request from a redirect

Tags: grails

Is it possible to run a request command on a set of multipartFile objects for a set of selected files that has been passed to an second action from an initial action that received them from an type file input html tag.

I can access the multipartfile object as a string in the redirected (second) action -

Such as:

```
form:org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@35d79259
```

But I am unable to run a request command such as request.getFiles - also I cannot cast it as a MultipartFile.

The redirect to intentional - let me explain what I'm trying to do in more detail:

I have a file upload web page with an input form that sends the selected files (multpartFile objects) to the action. Prior to uploading the files from the client I want the user to have a web page where he adds extra data to each file prior to uploading (metadata tags). To do this I was going to redirect to another action that displays a web page with the list of the files (having transferred the params data that contain the files selected from the original web page to the redirected action) and input fields for the user to add tags. In short the redirect is intentional.

I guess the correct way to do this is using js on the original web page - just wanted to see if I could do it this way instead?

-mike

Comment: This is not good. Perhaps for some test data it can work as a string, but there's a max length for a querystring. I don't know what it is and don't particularly care because I can't imagine a valid scenario where you'd be anywhere near that limit. In this case what will you do when one of the files is binary, or 1MB, or even 10k?

Answer (score 0):

In general redirects use GET, so there's nowhere for the form body and uploaded file(s) to go. POST/UPDATE/DELETE actions make changes, and a redirect is typically an indication that something went wrong, e.g. something mild like a url changed (301/302), or something more serious like an authenticated user trying to access a page they have no permission for, or an unauthenticated user trying to access anything guarded (401/403).

You wouldn't want to pick up where you left off from a lot of scenarios that trigger a redirect (and it wouldn't be practical at all) so it's common to not attempt to do anything with form or file upload data and let the user re-do the action.

Comment: @buck beckwitch The redirect is intentional - I have added more information to the original post which explains what I am trying to do.